# Android Firebase AB Testing

Tags: firebase, ab-testing, firebase-remote-config

I set up a firebase AB testing with Remote Config. I reached 10k users sample, after that firebase says "It is still too risky to declare a leader". So what is the minimum sample rate to declare an exact leader? Is there any official explanation in docs? Is there any formula how to calculate this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The sample size required to call an experiment depends on a couple of things, including the observed difference in the target metric: the smaller the observed effect of the treatment, the more observations you need to support the hypothesis that the observed difference is not due to  chance alone. See if [this paper](http://www.getvariant.com/white-papers/statistical-analysis-of-variant-experiments/) helps you. (Note further reading list at the end.)